# Android Market programmatically get exact number of downloads

Tags: java, php, android, download, google-play

Is there a way to get the exact number of downloads for MY app? I need to use that number on my website, but i can't figure out how to get the exact (or at least an approximate) number and not the interval which is displayed on the Android Market (Google Play) store page.
Is there an API or something that could help me achieve this from PHP or something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a package which provides some android market api http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/
maybe this will help you

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no API available, you could try to filter out the # of downloads out of the html you get.. Good luck!

Comment: hmm...how would i go about doing that? Looked a bit in the html code, but don't think it returns some precise values, it only returns the interval